# Using Field Calculator to put file name into field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, modelbuilder, nameerror

I am using ArcGIS ModelBuilder.

I want to use Field Calculator to put the file name into a field.
I created a field using add field.
But I don't know the function to call the file name.
What I've tried is `"!name!"`, `"!file.name!"`.

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro or the one from ArcMap?

Comment: There is no means within a Cursor object or Field Calculator tool to determine the data set/source name that is being processed, that information needs to be determined outside a Cursor object or Field Calculator and passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Parse Path](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path-ext.htm) model builder tool.

You can also use [arcpy.describe](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/describe.htm). The [Describe Object Properties](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/functions/describe-object-properties.htm) returns the path which you can field calculate into your attribute table.